# Finding salary same as roomate's

Tags: sql

I have three tables: `Student`, `Roommate`, `Salary`.

The columns are as follows:

**Student**

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
student_name             | varchar(30)
```

**Roommate**

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
roommate_id              | smallint
```

**Salary**

```
student_id (Primary Key) | smallint
salary                   | float(10,2)
```

Now  I need to print the name of the students same as their roommates.
Well, I was able to find the people who have the same salary. But I am not able to find whether they are roommates or not. How to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  And `JOIN` again.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried so far, and where you're stuck? Additionally, please add sample data and expected output to the question

Answer (score 5):

Following is the query which helps in Mysql

```
> SELECT st.student_name        
  FROM student st        
  JOIN roommate rm ON (rm.student_id = st.student_id)        
  JOIN salary st_salary ON (st.student_id = st_salary.student_id)        
  JOIN salary rm_salary ON (rm.roommate_id = rm_salary.student_id)      
  WHERE st_salary.salary = rm_salary.salary;
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT st.student_name FROM student st /* st - Student */
JOIN roommate rm ON (rm.student_id = st.student_id) /* rm - Student roommate */ 
JOIN salary st_salary ON (st.student_id = st_salary.student_id) /* st_salary - student's salary */ 
JOIN salary rm_salary ON /* (rm.roommate_id = rm_salary.student_id) /* rm_salary - student'ts roomate salary */ 
WHERE st_salary.salary = rm_salary.salary;
```

Comment: Comments added, hope they explain.